# SmartContracts - how to run function with "Erc.json" (javascript) (update)

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, web3js, erc20

**Hello guys,**

I have a question

I try to smart contract functions from erc.json standarts with JavaScript. To example: I need a random number function with metamask user address(account number) referance for backend

To basicly:

**Example JSON values:**

```
    {
    inputs: [{ internalType: 'address', name: 'UserKey', type: 'address' }],
    name: 'RandomNumber',
    outputs: [{ internalType: 'uint256', name: '', type: 'uint256' }],
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
  },
```

**Example smart contract function:**

```
        const daiToken = new web3.eth.Contract(
          ContractABI, // ABI
          address, // Sender address
          chainId
        )

        daiToken.methods
          .RandomNumber(address)
          .call(ContractABI)
          .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result)
          })
          .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err, 'err')
          })
```

**And here is the console prints:**

[image: ConsolePrint]

i hope i explained :)

and happy weekends..

(updated new error)

Answer (score 1):

Are you tried to change `<React.StrictMode><App /><React.StrictMode>` to `<App />` in your `index.js` file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work. got rid of an external error thanks :)

Comment: @zanthez Thank you for feedback. what error has remained?

Comment: Actually, doing what you said did not provide a solution to the issue, it was an external error and it was there before this action. so i am where i started. 
maybe another way? :)

Comment: hey @Maik Lowrey, i have a new step problem, i think it seems easier than the previous problem :) maybe if u want a check new error img?